# SqlCeResultSet.Read must be called before accesing underlaying entity - in spite of what is written in MSDN

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I would like to check with you issue I found. I am using SqlCeResultSet for fast inserts and updates. In following code, if resultSet.Read is commented, exception InvalidOperationException - "No data exists for the row/column." is thrown.

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Name from CLIENTS WHERE Id > 5 ORDER BY Id DESC";
var resultSet = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Scrollable | ResultSetOptions.Updatable);
// resultSet.Read();
resultSet.SetString(1, "UpdatedValue");
resultSet.Update();
```

According to the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedatareader.read%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) chapter Remarks this should not happen. *The default position of the SqlCeResultSet is the first record. Calling SqlCeResultSet.Read method immediately after creating the SqlCeResultSet will move the cursor to the second record. For SqlCeDataReader.Read, the behaviour is different from that of SqlCeResultSet.Read.*

I am something missing or this information in MSDN in wrong because I need to call Read on SqlCeResultSet first before I can read/write underlaying data?

Thanks for clarification